# A form inside of a project

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I downloaded a solution with an extra form (in separate folder) aside of the main project. My question is: how do I actually make use of it (i thought there will be a second .exe file, but there is only main one) ?

[image]

Comment: All the files should compile into one file, even if they are in a sub-folder.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to instantiate the class linked to the form window and show it. Something like:

```
(new Upgrades2.ControlForm()).Show();
```

Comment: It wont see it coz its inside a folder,

Answer (score 2):

Call that form like this anywhere in the program where you want it to appear

```
Upgrades2.ControlForm myForm = new Upgrades2.ControlForm();
myForm.ShowDialog();
```

U access it just like a normal form u just need to specifiy the folder first like the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Another way besides @yanguya995 answer is by importing a folder to a specific class.

```
using Upgrades2;
```

Then you can simply call the form like this.

```
ControlForm form = new ControlForm();
form.Show();
```

Or you can just type:

```
ControlForm form = new ControlForm();
```

If there is an error wrap just click `ctrl + .` There is context menu that will appear and choose `using Upgrades2` or `Upgrades2.ControlForm`

Comment: This is much cleaner, :)

Answer (score 0):

Most non trivial applications will have more than one form, but a single entry point (i.e. single .exe file).

The second form would probably be shown after the user does some action, like clicking a button - you can try searching for use of that form in the code.